# angular 11 router.navigateByUrl abd qyeryparams

Tags: angular10, angular11

Working with Angular 10 this was valid

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(targetUrl, {
            queryParams: {
                token: accessToken
            }
        });
```

Now (Angular 11) queryParams is not supported anymore what can I do to get the same functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 this.router.navigate([url], {
                relativeTo: this.route,
                queryParams: {token: accessToken},
              });
```

Try with this code snippet